# extract the value of an element node via XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Source-XML:

> ```
> <data>
>     <item>
>         <values>
>             <element1>
>                 <language>EN</language>
>                 <text>text</text>
>             </element1>
>             <element2>
>                 <language>DE</language>
>                 <text>Text</text> 
>             </element2>
>         </values>
>     </item>
>     <item>
>         <values>
>             <element5>
>                 <language>EN</language>
>                 <text>description</text>
>             </element5>
>             <element6>
>                 <language>DE</language>
>                 <text>Beschreibung</text> 
>             </element6>
>         </values>
>     </item> </data>
> ```

I want to get all the elements in language 'EN'. First I have a loop, where I saved the elment names in a variable. In the next step I want to get only the elements in language "EN". I need in the result of this step only the element-name and text which have the language 'EN' to build a table.

I tried this:

```
<xsl:param name="element" select="'element1'"/>  
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="data/item/values[local-name()=$element]/language[text()='EN']">

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And the output XSLT should be something like:

```
 <table id="123">   
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry>Name</entry>
                    <entry>Values</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry>
                        <ph>element1</ph>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>text</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry>
                        <ph>element5</ph>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>description</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
```

I know that there are other ways to solve this problem. But for other steps in the transformation it is important **to test every element separately.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: So, the first part of the problem is to filter/select the elements by parameter value? Or you want to output every `language = 'EN'` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="values/*[language = 'EN']">
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
             <xsl:element name="{current-group()/values/*[language = 'EN']/local-name()}">
                 <language>
                     <xsl:value-of select="descendant::language[text() = 'EN']"/>
                 </language>
                 <txt>
                     <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/values/*[language = 'EN']/text"/>
                 </txt>
             </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
You may do like this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="ENelements">
        <xsl:for-each select="/data/item/values/*[language='EN']">
           <element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="text" /></element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <table id="123">   
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry>Name</entry>
                    <entry>Values</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($ENelements)/*">
                     <row>
                        <entry>
                            <ph><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></ph>
                        </entry>
                        <entry><xsl:value-of select="." /></entry>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYig

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it could be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <table id="123">   
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1.0*"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry>Name</entry>
                    <entry>Values</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <xsl:variable name="elem" select="values/*[language='EN']" />
                    <row>
                        <entry>
                            <ph>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name($elem)"/>
                            </ph>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$elem/text"/>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```